# error: Package `xah-fly-keys-' is unavailable

Tags: init-file, package, terminal-emacs

I am setting up a `.emacs` file that I will be using in `Docker` containers.

I want to include [xah-fly-keys](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/ergoemacs_vi_mode.html) but I am getting this error message.

```
Package `xah-fly-keys-' is unavailable
```

When I start `Emacs` in a container I want `xah-fly-keys` to automatically be installed and activated.

[xah-fly-keys is in melpa](https://melpa.org/#/?q=xah-fly-keys)

The relevant parts of the `.emacs` file are:

```
;; add melpa repositories
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

;; Initialise packages
(package-initialize)

;; require use package
(package-install 'use-package)

;; add xah-fly-keys
(use-package xah-fly-keys
  :ensure t
  :pin melpa-stable)

;; activate xah-fly-keys
(xah-fly-keys 1)
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: `xah-fly-keys` is on Melpa but not Melpa-stable.

Comment: @xuchunyang thank you that helped me to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @xuchunyang's comment I was able to get this working.

Here is the revised `.emacs` which adds and uses melpa.

```
;; require package
(require 'package)

;; add melpa stable
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

;; add melpa
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

;; Initialise packages
(package-initialize)

;; require use package
(package-install 'use-package)

;; add xah-fly-keys using melpa
(use-package xah-fly-keys
  :ensure t
  :pin melpa)

;; activate xah-fly-keys
(xah-fly-keys 1)
```